# Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When my page loads, I would like to load data from a database. I am getting the data via angular's http module with something like this:

```
var getdata = function(){
    var params = {
        userId : 123,
    };
    $http.post("url", params)
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        alert("success");
    }).error(function(){
        alert("Failed to connect with server");
    });
};
```

In my controller I create a function called onLoad and call it following:

```
var onLoad = function(){
    getData();
    console.log("load page");
};
onLoad();
```

However, I get the following error when I navigate to the page
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

What could be going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us more code?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to get data and one more thing  i don't know about what depedencies you added in your controller in case if you didn't then this is the correct way to do so

```
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http({
     method : "POST",
    url : Your Url
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
});
  });
```

Comment: No, The `$http` syntax is absolutely correct. Just params should be defined by `body` or `data`

Comment: $http should be passed as a parameter to controller

Comment: I know Bro but He has not showed his dependency injection or parameters list in which he have defined his controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little mistake in your code that you have shown here is the spelling mistake `getData()` call is incorrect because you have defined your function with `getdata()`.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalaat/bkUEu/2921/) from your code and its working perfectly fine.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.sendPost = function() {
      var data = $.param({
        json: JSON.stringify({
          name: $scope.newName
        })
      });
      onLoad(data);
    }
    var getdata = function(data) {
      $http.post("/echo/json/", data)
        .success(function(data, status) {
          console.log(data)
          $scope.hello = data;
        })
    };

    var onLoad = function(data) {
      getdata(data);
      console.log("load page");
    };

    $scope.hello = {
      name: "Boaz"
    };
    $scope.newName = "";

  })
```

This error is not accrued by the code you have shown here. Please update your question with the relevant code after resolving this mistake.

Hope it helps